# how to get nested column from json file using apache spark in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, business-intelligence

I have  multiple json files. I have to parse it using apache spark. It has nested key init. I have to print all columns along with nested key.

The files has nested keys also.
I want to get all column name along with nested column name. How i can get it.

i tried this :

```
String jsonFilePath = "/home/vipin/workspace/Smarten/jsonParsing/Employee/Employee-01.json,/home/vipin/workspace/Smarten/jsonParsing/Employee/Employee-02.json";

String[] jsonFiles = jsonFilePath.split(",");

Dataset<Row> people = sparkSession.read().json(jsonFiles);
```

json structure in file as :

```
{ 
   "Name":"Vipin Suman",
   "Email":"vpn2330@gmail.com",
   "Designation":"Programmer",
   "Age":22 ,
   "location":
             {
             "City":"Ahmedabad",
             "State":"Gujarat"
             }
}
```

i am getting result as :

```
people.show(50, false);

Age | Designation | Email            | Name       | Location
------------------------------------------------------------
22  |Programmer   |vpn2330@gmail.com | Vipin Suman|[Ahmedabad,Gujarat]
```

I want data like :

```
Age | Designation | Email            | Name       | City      | State
------------------------------------------------------------
22  |Programmer   |vpn2330@gmail.com | Vipin Suman| Ahmedabad |Gujarat
```

or like :-

```
Age | Designation | Email            | Name       | Location
---------------------------------------------------------------
22  |Programmer   |vpn2330@gmail.com | Vipin Suman| Ahmedabad,Gujarat
```

if scema look like this

```
root
 |-- Age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Company: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Company Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Domain: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Designation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Test: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- City: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- City Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Pin: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- State: string (nullable = true)
```

and json structure

```
{ 
  "Name":"Vipin Suman",
  "Email":"vpn2330@gmail.com",
 "Designation":"Trainee Programmer",
 "Age":22 ,
 "location":
    {"City":
           {
            "Pin":324009,
            "City Name":"Ahmedabad"
           },
    "State":"Gujarat"
   },
 "Company":
          {
           "Company Name":"Elegant",
           "Domain":"Java"
          }, 
 "Test":["Test1","Test2"]

}
```

then how i can find nested key. and show the table in proper formet

Comment: Please prepare: input data example, what have you done and what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display data in above expected format you can use following code:

```
people.select("*", "location.*").drop("location").show
```

It will give following output:

```
+---+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+
|Age|Designation|            Email|      Name|     City|  State|
+---+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+
| 22| Programmer|vpn2330@gmail.com|VipinSuman|Ahmedabad|Gujarat|
+---+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much @himanshuIIITian for your reply.
Can i ask you one more question.

If i don't know that what key is nested how i can find it.

or if i have multiple nested column then how can i find and resolve that situation.

Comment: @Vpn_talent that is not possible because if we don't know the schema of a dataframe, then we cannot know whether it is nested or not.

Comment: @Vpn_talent Did this answer solved your problem ?

Comment: your answer solved my problem. but i am stuck with another problem.
So i have edited question. I am getting problem to show table in proper formet.
can you help me out i am beginner in spark

Comment: Any possible way to get "location" columns as "location.city" & "location.state" ?? I know we can do it "withColumnRenamed" method, But what if there were 100 columns?? Any suggestions would be helpful.